# Why is new apk not installed when older app is built on Android Studio or installed from Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I am trying to build apk for Chinese users. But I found some issue.

When the previous app is built from

1. Play Store
2. Android Studio

The apk file doesn't complete installation. And says `it's not installed`.

However, when I install older one by `adb install my_app.apk` or download the apk file from the internet and open/install, it installs successfully.

All the apk files has signed key(except for Android Studio build one). And I have no idea what's the problem. Or should it work & Am I wrong? I just tested Play Store one as `Internal App Sharing`. Since I can't test it out in the real market.

Comment: This happens when the app signatures are different or device has memory issue related app installation

Comment: is your app installed while running your project from android studio? if yes, make sure you have uninstalled for all users, from setting.

Comment: It should work, right?

Comment: You need to sign apk to be able to install it without issue when built with Android Studio